# Can a child be killed by a not-parent process?

Tags: unix, posix, parent-child

I'm making a project in which the *parent* forks a *terminator* process that kills one random child of the parent. It seems that it creates some problems.

Is it allowed?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-for-kill.html#Permission-for-kill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is that allowed: any process running as the same user or as the root user can kill any other process.

Running as my user ID in a terminal I can kill anything with my user ID. Even the terminal that I am running in. Or my GUI process.

The only process in Unix OS types that is immune to kill is PID 1 aka init. Because killing init would result in an immediate kernel panic. If PID 1 exits for any reason, such as an internal bug and segmentation fault, there's an immediate kernel panic.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed. Write the following code in `parent.sh`

```
terminator() {
   sleep 2;
   echo "(terminator) Going to kill Pid $1"
   kill -9 "$1" && echo "(terminator) Pid $1 killed"
}

sleep 7 &
sleep 7 &
sleep 7 &
pid=$!
echo "Random pid=${pid} will be killed"
sleep 7 &
sleep 7 &
terminator ${pid} &
echo "All started"
ps -ef | sed -n '1p; /sleep 7/p'
sleep 3
echo "After kill"
ps -ef | sed -n '1p; /sleep 7/p'
```

Background processes are childs. The terminator child will kill a random other child after 2 seconds.

```
Random pid=6781 will be killed
All started
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
notroot   6779  6777  0 16:59 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 7
notroot   6780  6777  0 16:59 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 7
notroot   6781  6777  0 16:59 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 7
notroot   6782  6777  0 16:59 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 7
notroot   6783  6777  0 16:59 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 7
(terminator) Going to kill Pid 6781
(terminator) Pid 6781 killed
parent.sh: line ...:  6781 Killed                  sleep 7
After kill
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
notroot   6779  6777  0 16:59 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 7
notroot   6780  6777  0 16:59 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 7
notroot   6782  6777  0 16:59 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 7
notroot   6783  6777  0 16:59 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 7
```

Comment: Ok but doing so in which way I have to wait it? I have to wait it from the parent or from terminator?

Comment: you can add `wait; echo "Childs finished"` at the end of the parent.sh script.